# log4net: PropertyFilter not working

Tags: log4net

I have configured this filter for one of my log4net appenders (uses AdoNetAppender):

```
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
      <key value="c" />
      <stringToMatch value="Stribe.Kernel" />
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

I'm probably doing something really wrong, but been trying to figure it out for an hours now and it's driving me crazy.
What i want the filter to do is deny all entries, except those who's logger name begin (or contain, both fine for me) with "Stribe.Kernel"

Also tried something with  but i cannot get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "tried something with" ... with what? And: what *do* you experience, is everything logged or nothing?

Comment: everything is logged...

this is what i have tried with regexToMatch: 
<Key value="logger" />
<RegexToMatch value="^((?!Stribe\.Kernel).)*$" />
<AcceptOnMatch value="false" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you attach the appender to the logger "Stribe.Kernel" instead of the root logger like this:

```
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
</root>
<logger name="Stribe.Kernel">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="YourAppender" />
</logger>
```

If you are using other loggers you can still attach them to the root logger.